# Upgrade old motherboard to core 2 dual core

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a Ga8i945g (gigabyte motherboard) now this cpu is intel pentium 4 3.01ghz. (Socket 755).  I want upgrade this cpu to intel core 2 dual core.    This cpu is in the motherboard cpu support list.  But below Since BIOS Version is N/A!!!

So i dont know this motherboard support intel core 2 dual core?

Comment: Where is the support list?

Comment: If you are trying to get performance improvements from a 17-year-old motherboard, it might be time for an upgrade. Even if it would be supported (which it's not), a first-generation Dual Core chip is not going to give you much of an improvement for modern applications.

Answer (score 1):

It says at the top of [the page](https://www.gigabyte.com/Ajax/SupportFunction/Getcpulist?Type=Product&Value=1909) (in red text for emphasis) that "N/A" means "not supported".

You can't do it.

The reason these processors are listed even though they are not supported is because the list includes all processors that would physically fit in the socket. However, the physical fit is not the only requirement for compatibility.